# Unable to load Cast Sender framework on Chrome Android

Tags: video.js, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm trying to implement chromecast on my nuxt(vuejs) webapp, cast framework loading and working well on chrome desktop. But can't load it on android chrome version.

This code working on desktop and i can cast without problems.

```
window["__onGCastApiAvailable"] = function(isAvailable) {
   if (isAvailable) {
      that.initializeCastApi();
   };
}
let ccFramework = document.createElement("script");
ccFramework.setAttribute("src","https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1");
ccFramework.async = true;
ccFramework.onload = () => {
    console.log("loaded");
};
document.getElementById("chromecast").appendChild(ccFramework);
```

On destop working i can cast on my receiver app.
[Videojs player on chrome Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Fp2.png)

But on android, default browser settings seem to be used instead Chromecast sender framework and provided configuration.. (Chrome V 74.0.3729.136)
[Videojs player on chrome Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAifT.png)

Edit : Same problem append in Google Chrome SDK provided demo :

[Google Demo Chrome Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7NPR.png)

[Google Demo Chrome Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks17W.png)

Any idea to force framework loading or provide configuration to default chromecast detection ? Or in worst case scenario disable Chromecast in this video on android chrome ?

Comment: Ok, I know very little of this subject area...just enough to be able to ask a (maybe foolish) question: It appears you're using 'v1' sender.  Any reason for not trying/using 'v2'?

Comment: I don't see any documentation / references to V2 on chrome browser.  This version seem to be called V1 on the url but V2 or V3 on Google documentation or youtube presentation tutorial. [google cast chrome documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender/ )

Comment: (I've not played with 'sender', but I do PLAN to in the future.)  But, if it's simple/straight-forward to try either v2 or v3, it might be worth a try.  It could be just that various tutorials were written a different date, and that v3 is newest and should be preferred, and works for ALL those various contexts that you mention.

Comment: Do you have link to this V3 (or V2) for chrome ? I didn't find anything.

Comment: Ok, I did find the V2 docs that I'd seen.  But, it might be something slightly different...it includes the abbreviation "CAF" in it.  Here's the link:  https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender/integrate